# Javascript - Click to rotate image infinitely and click again to stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rotatetransform

I've been trying to figure out how to get this script to rotate an image infinitely onclick and then stop it when you click it again. Can anyone modify it to get it to do that?

```
$(function() {

    var $rota = $('.spin'),
        degree = 0,
        timer;

    function rotate() {    
        $rota.css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
        // timeout increase degrees:
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            ++degree;
            rotate(); // loop it
        },5);
    }

    rotate();    // run it!

});
```

Comment: What browsers you tried? You might need the vendor prefixes...

Answer (score 1):

you could create a bool to determine if the element has been clicked, change it on click and stop the process if the click has happened.

```
$(function() {

    var $rota = $('.spin'),
        degree = 0,
        clicked = false,
        timer;

    $rota.on('click', function() { clicked = true; return false; } );

    function rotate() { 
        if ( clicked )   
            $rota.css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
            // timeout increase degrees:
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
               ++degree;
               rotate(); // loop it
            },5);
        }

        rotate();    // run it!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setInterval` and `clearInterval` instead of `setTimeout`:

```
function rotate() {    
    $rota.css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
    ++degree;
}

var loop;
$rota.click(function() { 
    if(loop) {
         clearInterval(loop);
         loop = false;
    }
    else {
        loop = setInterval(rotate, 5);
    }
});
```

You can read up on setInterval [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {

    var $rota = $('.spin')

    $rota.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this.data('rotating')){
            clearInterval($this.data('rotating'));
            $this.data('rotating', false)
        } else {
            $this.data('rotating', setInterval(function(){
                var degree = $this.data('degree') || 0;
                $this.css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
                $this.data('degree', ++degree)
            }, 5));
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cy22f/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var $rota = $('img'), degree = 0, timer, enabled;
    var rotate = function() {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            ++degree;
            $rota.css({
              transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
            });
        },5);
    };
    $rota.on('click', function(){
       enabled = !enabled;
       enabled ? rotate() : clearInterval(timer);
    });
});
```